# Issue: How to retrieve members of a set of AzureAD groups using PowerShell Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having a problem getting all members of a range of groups from AzureAD.
Who can help me?
Thank you in advance
With the script below I can retrieve the members of 1 group and that works fine.

```
Connect-MgGraph
$GROUP_NAME = 'SUG-APP-MAN-SPBI_BICC-P'
$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$GROUP_NAME'"
$members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id
$users = @()
foreach ($member in $members)
{
$user = Get-MgUser -UserId $member.Id
$users += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Group = $group.DsplayName;
Name = $user.DisplayName;
USERPRINCIPALNAME = $user.Mail}
}
$users | Format-Table
```

This I am trying to retrieve all members of a range of groups.
The problem is how I define variable $GROUP_NAME

```
Connect-MgGraph
$GROUP_LIST = Get-MgGroup
foreach ($Group in $GROUP_LIST)
{
$GROUP_NAME = $GROUP_LIST
$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$GROUP_NAME'"
$members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id
$users = @()
foreach ($member in $members)
{
$user = Get-MgUser -UserId $member.Id
$users += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Group = $group.DsplayName;
Name = $user.DisplayName;
USERPRINCIPALNAME = $user.Mail}
}
}
$users | Format-Table
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: take a look on this site https://techlabs.blog/categories/azure/get-members-of-an-azure-ad-group-using-powershell-get-azureadgroupmember-and-export-to-csv

Comment: # define variable for aad  group
$AADGroup = "All UK Staff"

# get Azure AD Group members and export to CSV
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $AADGroup | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select DisplayName, Mail | Export-Csv -path "c:\temp\$AADGroup-members-$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).csv"

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. 
In your example, you specify a fixed value of $AADGroup = "All UK Staff"
I want $AADGroup to always collect a different value.
I pick up the groups with Get-MgGroup.
See first line of script above.

The mebers of each group found must be shown.
So not from 1 group, as in your example

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "GroupMember.Read.All", "Group.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All"
$GROUP_LIST = Get-MgGroup |select Id, DisplayName, Description, GroupTypes
$Group=""
$users = @()
foreach ($Group in $GROUP_LIST) {

  #$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$Group.DisplayName'"
  $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id

  Write-Host $Group.DisplayName
  foreach ($member in $members) {
    $user = Get-MgUser -UserId $member.Id
    $users += New-Object PSObject -Property @{Group = $group.DisplayName;
      Name                                          = $user.DisplayName;
      USERPRINCIPALNAME                             = $user.Mail
    }
  }  
}

$users | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanxs Kemal, New challenge. How to create a list of groups with only field DisplayName?

Comment: @LH1959 `$azureAdgroupS = (Get-MgGroup).DisplayName`

Comment: @Kemal K
Get-AzureAdGroup is not a valid command in Powershell Ms Graph

Comment: @LH1959 i will update the code Msgraph

Comment: Thanks, the problem is already solved

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-MgGroupTransitiveMember -GroupId $groupId
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.